# How to trigger an Ansible Tower Job template from Github branch commit?

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

How can I trigger a job in Ansible Tower using its API on a Github branch commit?

I could use a Github webhook but when triggered by a push it occurs regardless of branch. I'm wondering if the webhook payload could provide info but I m not sure how to utilize it within the job. Am I on the right track or is there a better approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pipeline using [GitHub actions and conditionals](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths).
For example:

```yaml
on:
  # Trigger the workflow on push or pull request,
  # but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
```

Taken from [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#on).

Answer (score 0):

The webhook payload does provide information. Check the extra variables in the output of a job triggered by a webhook. More information about how the payload is exposed as an extra variable can be found here:

https://docs.ansible.com/automation-controller/4.1.0/html/userguide/webhooks.html#payload-output

You can use the values of the payload variables to perform conditional actions with Ansible.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31548337)